# How to create a subfolder of a Uri folder, Android 10+?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, create-directory

It was here before SDK 29, but now it is required.

My app creates a cascade of folders to manage its content. All the content is meant to be stored inside any folder the user chooses, but for the living hell, I can't figure out, how to **create a folder in a Uri folder and access it later** (because *Storage access framework - ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE*).

I tried to create a folder and a file inside using `DocumentFile`, which worked well (now that doesn't work either), on the other hand, when I copied some files to that directory, it prohibited me from accessing those files in any way. I need to access those files even if I move them as I have a copy of the older content I had on a different device, but now it cannot access those files.

One more thing to add, the first time I tried to log the filenames it worked. But when I ran the code once again, it gave me SecurityExceptions about not using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to get those files' references. But it should give me full power over the selected directory, right?

Used code to create a subFile/subFolder:

```java
DocumentFile file = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, data.getData());

public DocumentFile getChild(String name) {
    DocumentFile child = file.findFile(name);
    if (name.matches(".*\\..{3,4}$")) {
        String mimetype = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
                name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.')));
        return child != null ? child : file.createFile(
                mimetype == null ? "application/dat" : mimetype, name);
    }
    return child != null ? child : file.createDirectory(name);
}
```

Any reference to a manual I couldn't find would help.

Comment: You can instantiate a DocumentFile variable for the obtained uri. Then use DocumentFile.createFile/Directory.

Comment: I tried that, but when I debugged the process, it throws an access denial exception when creating the directory (or file).

Comment: Why are you using findFile()? Please OR try to create a file OR try to create a directory. Where and when do you call getChild()?

Comment: `tried to create a folder and a file inside using DocumentFile, which worked well` Well then look at the subject of your post. Why asking how? I find it all quite confusing.

Comment: `it prohibited me from accessing those files in any way. ` Well if that is the real problem then where is your code?

Comment: `the first time I tried to log the filenames it worked` Where is the code where you try to log names? Pretty unclear what things you are doing and when.

Comment: you have it here, file.create* simply does not work. It prohibits me from using the file. Also, I thing showing how I log file.getName() is unnecessary.

Comment: `simply does not work.` If it does not work that no file or directory is created. `It prohibits me from using the file. ` file? But... it did not work. So there is no file i would say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited, you need to add getflags on creating anything in folder.

```
final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags() & 
(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | 
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

The object t is a shared prefernce just to save the strings uri, you can switch them.out for your object.

Use this when you need to create folder, use in public void as function

```
Intent intent = new  
Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE); 
startActivityForResult(intent, 
NEW_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Use this to get activity result of  created folder

```
if (_resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
if (_requestCode == 
NEW_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE) { if (_data != 
null) { Uri currentUri = 
_data.getData();
DocumentFile pickedDir = 
DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, 
currentUri);
DocumentFile newDir =
pickedDir.createDirectory("MyFolder");

final int takeFlags = 
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | 
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION; 

} } }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try as soon as I can.

Comment: Also, what is the object `t`?

Comment: Shared preferences

Comment: I just edited with full code, i jist figured out, you must gain permission to all folders you create also with saf. Their may be a way to do this without asking user if so ill try to let you know.

Comment: I was wrong you dont need to to ask for every subfolder, uou just need to put get flags